# form tags missing while rendering javascript templates in chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

I have a aspx page in which i have a form like this.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
.
.
.
</form>
```

Now i'm using mutliple javascript templates(trimpath) in this page and each of these tpls have a form tag inside it.

Now after rendering everything, in IE i get multiple form tag in the page, but in chrome i have my rendered tpls and everything inside the main form tag(aspx) page, and there are no other form tags.

IE(devloper tools)

```
<form id="form1" action="abc.aspx" method="post"> //main form tag of aspx page

<form id="tpl1">rendered tags of tpl
..</form>

<form id="tpl2">rendered tags of tpl
..</form>

</form>
```

but in chrome

```
<form id="form1" action="abc.aspx" method="post"> //main form tag of aspx page

rendered tags of tpl
....

rendered tags of tpl
....

</form>
```

any idea why is it happening like this?

Answer (score 1):

It's because forms-within-forms aren't semantically correct or valid, and modern browsers tend to attempt to auto-correct invalid HTML when they render the page.

Comment: so can you tell me how to turn off that auto correct html in chrome

Comment: @mushabir pretty sure you can't, the only answer here is to no nest form tags because it's invalid

Comment: i have got my solution, i removed form tag from my aspx page and its working fine for me.